# Visual Studio: Change platform from win32 to x64 and keep ALL project settings?

Tags: visual-studio, fltk

I am trying to build [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) on x64 platform in VS13 environment. It's a large solution with many projects and I would like to convert them all - so far so good, there are many tutorials how to do it. The problem is that the conversion fails to keep all my individual projects setting, e.g Intermediate Directories under Configuration Properties even though I have "Copy settings from: Win32" selected.

Building fails because in the original settings each project has it's own Intermediate Directory but after the change everything is one folder, so is the .pbd files (which is reduced to one file). Probably there are more problems.

Is there a way to keep all the Win32 settings? There are tons of projects and converting them one by one would be an overkill.

Comment: No, the wizard changes the setting intentionally to avoid a collision with the 32-bit build output.  Nothing you can't do in a few seconds by selecting all the projects and changing the setting, assuming it has some pattern to it.  This is a fairly typical open source issue,  don't forget to submit your patch so that the next programmer can take advantage of your changes.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this :( I just corrected the library projects and left the demos as they were.

Comment: @Elena, were you able to compile this for x64? If yes can you please share how you actives it? I am looking for the same solution. Even I am getting those words when I try to copy win32 setting.

Comment: @programmer I think I manually copied all the win32 settings into x64. However, I did it only for the libraries (they are not so many, just a few) and not for the huge number of demos as I didn't need them.

Comment: @Elena, would you be able to share some more details (like which files and what settings to copy)? I am looking for building FLTK as x64. Also do you know how to build with runtime as 'Multi-threaded /MT'? Currently the build is successful with runtime as 'Milti-threaded-DLL'.

Comment: @programmer I no longer have access to the modified FLTK project itself so I cannot really check. Mostly I had to manually edit the Intermediate Directories under Configuration Properties so that each project has its own folder for its .pdb file. Everything else is described here I believe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx

Comment: @programmer Also I don't remember what I did to have MT but from what I read in the forums right now is the suggestion to install Microsoft Redistributable Package for your VS (and I remember having done so), To help you more you need to share the error that you get when you try to change this setting.

Comment: @Elena, thanks, I could build it for x64 after manually changing this. However I get these errors when I try to build using x64 and adding the .lib files:  
identifier "XPoint" is undefined FLTK ..\FL\Fl_Device.H 
cannot open source file "X11/Xlocale.h" FLTK ..\FL\fl_utf8.h
cannot open source file "X11/Xlib.h" FLTK ..\FL\fl_utf8.h
cannot open source file "X11/Xutil.h" FLTK ..\FL\x.H
cannot open source file "X11/Xatom.h" FLTK ..\FL\x.H
identifier "Region" is undefined FLTK ..\FL\x.H
declaration is incompatible with "void fl_open_display()" (declared at line 58) FLTK ..\FL\x.H 59

Comment: Oh yes, because FLTK lib has a check "ifdef WIN32" when includes this library. I just added WIN32 to my project definitions (the one that uses fltk.lib) and it worked. Now that I think about it, I am not quite sure what the consequences of this act are.

Comment: @Elena, You mentioned: " just added WIN32 to my project definitions (the one that uses fltk.lib) and it worked.", can you explain a bit on this please? Really appreciate your help here.

Comment: @programmer Follow the instruction on the bottom of this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx on how to add a definition. Add WIN32 exactly as it is.